# type mismatch; found : Some[String] required: play.api.templates.Html

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, type-mismatch

I am new to scala as well as Java Play. I was looking at a code which looks like this but I am getting the above error. I am unable to fix this despite adding the curly braces etc. Any help is much appreciated.
Sorry I forgot to mention that the error shows up in @main. Even as I replace Some(username) with @main(username) there is no respite. routes this is how the relevant code looks

conf/routes

```
GET     /Login                controllers.Application.Login(username:String)
```

app/view/Login.scala.html looks like this

```
@(username: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader)

@main(Some(username)) {

<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Login <small>You are Logging in as @username</small></h1>
</div>

<div id="onError" class="alert-message error">
    <p>
        <strong>Oops!</strong> <span></span>
    </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(function() {

        var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket
        var loginSocket = new WS("@routes.Application.UserLogin(username).webSocketURL()")

        var receiveEvent = function(event) {
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data)

            // Handle errors
            if(data.error) {
                loginSocket.close()
                $("#onError span").text(data.error)
                $("#onError").show()
                return
            } else {
                $("#onChat").show()
            }


        }

    })

</script>
}
```

Comment: Please indicate where the error is thrown (I assume it is in ``var loginSocket = ...``).

Comment: Why the downvote? It seems the community has gotten a lot more impatient with new users.

Comment: @appy g, what line (and character) is highlighted in red when you try to display the page? It will help if you provide that info. Certainly, `@main(Some(username))` seems like it should be `@main(username)`.

Comment: @huynhjl I have made the edits.

Comment: @mhs I forgot to indicate that (Though I kinda pasted the log as heading..Sorry about that)

Comment: Can you please post the first 10 lines of main.scala.html? calling @main(Html(username)) makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, you have provided `Some[String]` where `play.api.templates.Html` is expected. The most likely candidate based on the code you've provided is:

```
@main(Some(username)) {
```

Based on that I would replace it with:

```
@main(Html(username)) {
```

That assumes that the first parameter of the *main view* is of type `Html`.